# My wrapper function is missing a variable?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Due to a peculiar error I was having, I decided to wrap a function like so to resolve said error:

```
UFUNCTION()         
void OnBoxOverlapWrapper(UPrimitiveComponent* /*ignored*/, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult & SweepResult)
{
    OnBoxOverlap(OtherActor, OtherComp, OtherIndex, bFromSweep, SweepResult);
}
```

However, when I try to compile my code, the line that sets up OnBoxOverlapWrapper produces this: `Error: Missing variable name`. This is the only time that the wrapper has been declared in the function, so this shouldn't be happening. What's especially bizarre is the fact that when I used a similar kind of wrapper for another function, it did not produce such an error:

```
UFUNCTION()
void OnBoxEndOverlapWrapper(UPrimitiveComponent* /*ignored*/ AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherIndex)
{
    OnBoxEndOverlap(OtherActor, OtherComp, OtherIndex);
} //this code does not produce an error
```

What's going on here?

Comment: show the exact error message

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to throw it in there! I'll add it now.

Comment: in the second one I guess you are missing a comma before `AActor` ... are there any other typoes?

Comment: Does it make any difference to give a name to the first parameter (instead of `/*ignored*/` ) ?

Comment: @M.M The typo was just in this post lol; I just double checked and the real code doesn't have it. When I give a name to the first parameter it gives me the following error:

 `unresolved external symbol: "private vvoid_cdecl AAICharacter::OnBoxOverlap (8)" referenced in function "private: void_cdecl AAICharacter::OnBoxOverlapWrapper(8)"`

This is a really simplified version of the actual error, which included a bunch of random letters and nonsense within the parentheses (I replaced them with the number 8, for reference)

Comment: That means you haven't written a body for the function `OnBoxOverlap` you are calling

Comment: @M.M You got it! That resolved the issue. Type that out as an answer so I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out you needed to write a body for the `OnBoxOverlap` function .